# SQL obtain values between second and third forward slash

Tags: sql-server, substring, character, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server, I am trying to obtain the values between the second and third forward slash (`/`) character. The length of the numbers can vary so `substring(column, 8, 10)` wouldn't work.

```
123/123/123456789/12
```

What I am trying to get in the current example is: 123456789

Comment: By second and third character you mean second and third **forward slash** char (`/`) - right?

Comment: @marc_s, correct

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @Stuckat1337, Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15) (KB4577775) - 13.0.5850.14 (X64)   Sep 17 2020 22:12:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 4 parts to your data as shown you can abuse the *parsename* function:

```
declare @string varchar(50) = '123/123/123456789/12';

select ParseName(Replace(@string,'/','.'),2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization*.

This method is generic regardless how many tokens are in place.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('123/123/123456789/12'),
('123/123/9876543210/12');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/';

SELECT t.* 
   , ThirdToken = c.value('(/root/r[position() eq 3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | ThirdToken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123/123/123456789/12 | 123456789 |
| 2 | 123/123/9876543210/12 | 9876543210 |

Comment: I normally look forward to your XML solutions, but considering 2016, this is expensive compared to the JSON approach and particularly Stu's parsename().

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I concur.  Please upvote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on 2016, consider the following

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 (1,'123/123/123456789/12')

Select A.ID
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(SomeCol,'/','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
ID  Pos3
1   123456789
```

If you only need the ***single*** value, there is no need for the `CROSS APPLY`

```
Select A.ID
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(SomeCol,'/','","')+'"]','$[2]')
 From  @YourTable A
```